# How to put if condition in select value? using react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to put if condition in **value={displaySelectedDocument}** that if the **displaySelectedDocument** is null the value will automatic 1.

```
<Select 
    isSearchable
    options={docsClass}
    className={classes.selection}
    value={displaySelectedDocument}
    onChange={(itemValue) => {
         setDisplaySelectedDocumentn(itemValue)
         setFieldValue("documentId",itemValue.value)
    }}
    name='documentId'/>
```

**UPDATE**

iv'e tried this

```
value={displaySelectedDocument !== null ? displaySelectedDocument : 1} // I also tried 0 and "" but it didnt work
```

i tried to **console.log(displaySelectedDocument)** in the result is `{}`

[image]

Comment: If you want this to be the case for any falsey value, you could do `value={displaySelectedDocument || 1}`. However if you just need it for `null`, something like `value={displaySelectedDocument === null ? 1 : displaySelectedDocument}`

Answer (score 1):

```js
<Select 
    isSearchable
    options={docsClass}
    className={classes.selection}
    value={displaySelectedDocument || 1}
    onChange={(itemValue) => {
         setDisplaySelectedDocumentn(itemValue)
         setFieldValue("documentId",itemValue.value)
    }}
    name='documentId'/>
```

if displaySelectedDocument can take on falsey values (eg 0) and still be valid

```js
<Select 
    isSearchable
    options={docsClass}
    className={classes.selection}
    value={displaySelectedDocument !== null ? displaySelectedDocument : 1}
    onChange={(itemValue) => {
         setDisplaySelectedDocumentn(itemValue)
         setFieldValue("documentId",itemValue.value)
    }}
    name='documentId'/>
```

if you want to also make sure displaySelected isnt an empty object, it might be better to create a variable to avoid making your code look complex

Here's how it would look without making a var

```js
<Select 
    isSearchable
    options={docsClass}
    className={classes.selection}
    value={displaySelectedDocument !== null ? displaySelectedDocument !== null ? Object.keys(displaySelectedDocument).length > 1 ? displaySelectedDocument : 1:1}
    onChange={(itemValue) => {
         setDisplaySelectedDocumentn(itemValue)
         setFieldValue("documentId",itemValue.value)
    }}
    name='documentId'/>
```

Thats kind of hard to read and comprehend. But if you created a var before you return JSX its easier to read:

```js
const isValidDoc = displaySelectedDoc !== null && 
  Object.keys(displaySelectedDoc).length > 1
return (
  {/*other JSX*/}
  <Select 
    isSearchable
    options={docsClass}
    className={classes.selection}
    value={ isValidDoc ? displaySelectedDocument : 1}
    onChange={(itemValue) => {
         setDisplaySelectedDocumentn(itemValue)
         setFieldValue("documentId",itemValue.value)
    }}
    name='documentId'/>
)
```

Comment: the console result is `{}` not 1

Comment: that is the value displaySelectedDocument has in it, then

Comment: edited answer to deal with displaySelectedDocument being an empty object

Comment: Unexpected token, expected ":"